# Uber oauth2.0 login redirecting too many time

Tags: uber-api

[image]

I'm trying to set up a 3rd party service that uses the Uber APIs to pull client history. I've got a local Flask app running which does the auth_flow and redirects to the Uber login page. After entering correct credentials, it appears that the redirect is never ending, hence the error in the image posted.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, request, flash, url_for, redirect, \
     render_template, abort, send_from_directory, redirect
from uber_rides.auth import AuthorizationCodeGrant

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('flaskapp.cfg')

# Configure Uber Oauth2.0
auth_flow = AuthorizationCodeGrant(
    '<client_id>',
    'history',
    '<client_secret>',
    'http://localhost:8080'
    )

@app.route('/')
def index():
    auth_url = auth_flow.get_authorization_url()
    return redirect(auth_url, code=302)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

That is my code. In the Uber developer dashboard, I've added http://localhost:8080 as the redirect URI and checked the `history` option under scopes.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any route for the callback ... Looks like what happens is: User opens app, gets redirected to auth_url (I assume that's the Uber auth page), user authorizes your app, user gets redirected to http://localhost:8080. This redirect is hitting the index route and user gets back to auth_url. The second time a user sees the Uber auth page his session is still valid and he gets redirect back to http://localhost:8080.. This creates a never-ending loop.

A solution would be set the redirect URL to hit a different callback route, e.g. http://localhost:8080/callback.